# Video stream in WebRTC stops when using LTE

Tags: ios, react-native, webrtc

I wrote a program that streams video between two IOS devices (using React and react-native-webrtc, if that matters).  It works fine, using WiFi.

Under LTE, establishing and maintaining the stream apparently works fine, the stream object has the right structure, but the video just doesn't show up.

What is peculiar is that if I establish a stream under LTE and then, once the program is running (and the screen is black), I turn on WiFi, the same stream starts conducting data and the screen lights up.

Also, it doesn't matter which of the two devices only has access to LTE: the video is blocked in either direction.

I'm wondering if there is some setting, either in the code or the phone, that says, "OK to transmit video over cellular" -- or if it's just not allowed (by AT&T, the carrier in question).

Comment: If WebRTC is using UPnP to get a publicly accessible IP-address, this can be the cause of the issue, because your carrier can simply forbid UPnP port forwarding.

Comment: @DisableR -- do you have any idea how I could check for such a possibility?  Thanks.

Comment: @DisableR -- I found [this comment](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/discuss-webrtc/fP8QCqYfx3E) saying WebRTC does _not_ use UPnP.

Comment: I'm running into a similar issue. The WebRTC connection is successfully established, but I never get a video feed.  When I look at WebRTC stats, I see very high packet loss on the video transport (>50%).

In iOS logs, I see:
`#I 1.1 Carrier does not support entitlement FaceTimeOverCellular`

Wondering if the cell provider could be blocking video traffic?